# I've downloaded the file to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS but I can't open it. Some advice?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

The file is 'ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' and there is another one with the same name. I couldn't open it so I neither could install the new version. I'm really new into updates and ubuntu world, please help! Thanks! FJC

Answer (score 2):

iso is a CD/DVD image format. You have to burn it to a disc and boot your machine from it to install Ubuntu. 
Here you have a full step-by-step guide on [how to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/152902/367990).

Comment: burning to a disk is outdated and depreciated. Most of the .iso are larger then a CD and thus need to go onto a DVD. DVD are expensive. For the most part , the .iso is written to a flash drive, which is nothing like burning. Flash drives are less expensive then DVD and recyclable.

Comment: I know but a) creating bootable usb drives is a bit more complicated than just burning a disc and b) for me the word disc includes CDs and DVDs, which I also mentioned. c) There are also some ?Ubuntu versions that still fit on a CD. And d) I still like boot discs better than flash drives, but this is my personal opinion.

Comment: I myself went for usb, but took me 2 hours more to understand. I went for the usb solution, because i had no empty dvd at home. DVDś aren expensive anymore. I certainly would advice a DVD for ease of use.